# C# Entityframework saving record with many to many navigation property

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm creating my models using ADO.NET (from mysql db). I have 6 tables :

customer, shoppinglist, customer_shoppinglist (that has two FK one for customerid and the other one for shoppinglist id), item and a shoppinglist_item table (that has two FK one for shoppinglist id and the other one for item id)

each shopping list contains a list of items - and each item can be related to several shopping lists.

each customer contains a list of shopping lists- and each shopping list can be related to several customers.

Now I Have 2 problems:

1) I want to add a new customer that has 3 shopping lists. one that exist in the db and two new ones that contains an existing items in their item list.
This is my code (which works well if I'm adding to customer only one new shopping list):

```
    public static void saveCustomer(Customer customer){
          using (var context = new DBContext()) {
                Customer customerToAdd= new Customer(customer);
                foreach (ShoppingList shoppingList in customer.shoppingLists) {
                    if (shoppingList .id == 0) {
                        customerToAdd.shoppingLists.Add(new ShoppingList(shoppingList));
                    }
                    else
                        customerToAdd.shoppingLists.Add(shoppingList);
                }

                foreach (ShoppingList shoppingList in customer.shoppingLists) {
                    foreach(Item item in shoppingList.items){
                        context.items.Attach(item);
                    }
                    if (shoppingList.id != -1) {
                        context.shoppingLists.Attach(shoppingList);
                    }
                }
                context.customers.Add(customerToAdd);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
     }
```

And

```
 public ShoppingList(ShoppingList oShoppingList) {
        this.id = -1;
        this.name = oShoppingList.name;
        this.description = oShoppingList.description;
    }
```

(The new shopping list in customer has id = 0 when function is called)

I get this error :

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

on line :

```
context.items.Attach(item);
```

2) What should I do if I want to add a new item to the customer shopping list items?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are attaching an object with the same ID to the context (0/-1). 
You could fix this by creating a seperate function that creates a DbContext,attaches and saves and then kills the Context.

Like so:

```
   public bool addShoppingItem(Item item){
           using (var context = new DBContext()) 
           {
            context.items.Add(item);
            context.SaveChanges();
           }
   }
```

Comment: The object that has the same id (-1) is a ShoppingList not Item. When I'm attaching the item I'm trying to tell it that this item exist in the db so when it adds the shoppingList object he should connect the shoppingList object items to the existing items in the db (i.e update the shoppinglist_item table but not the item table).

Comment: Are you saying all your items of the shopping list dont have ID 0 when you add them to the objectstatemanager?

Comment: Yes, each has unique id (the customer given to the function above is copied from the db and then edited - each edit is causing the id to change to 0 - that way I can tell if I need to add a new one or connect it to an existing one)

Comment: So the error may come from the fact that the shoppinglists have the same items and then you attach it to the same context. So you have 3 shoppinglists attaching the same id a bunch of times? Point is having one context to handle all of this is making problems.